# Horizontal shift when using scalebox and input within center environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, input

I would like to use `\scalebox` to scale a `TikZ` picture (included with `\input`) that is located inside a `center` environment (I don't need a float environment in this specific case). But `\scalebox` introduces a slight shift to the left such that the content is not exactly centered anymore.

```
\documentclass[DIV=10]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{temp.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\scalebox{1.0}{%
  \input{temp.tikz}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

For demonstration purposes, I used `1.0` as a scale factor. You would expect the output to be the same as without using the `\scalebox` environment, but that is not the case.

What is the cause of this problem and how may I solve it?

Comment: Try `T%` -- it looks the same for me then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, looks better, although there's still some very small shift, but that might be due to rounding errors when the scale factor is 1.0. However, when using `\include` to include some `tikzpicture` environment, adding `%` does not work for me.

Comment: Well, you did not mention that you would use `\include` the `tikzpicture`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I tried some different combinations and did not suspect that this would make any difference. In order to keep the MWE as simple as possible, I omitted those details.

Comment: Well, I just tried to use `\include` within `\scalebox` -- there were errors. `\input` does work and appending `%` after \input{foo}` does work too

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just updated the question. For me, removing the scalebox does result in the black box being moved slightly to the right.

Comment: It does not wobble, if you use `\begin{tikzpicture}%...\end{tikzpicture}%`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, that finally works. If you can explain why, please make this an answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: Well, no, I do not understand it right now what the real cause of this is. You don't need the `%` if `\scalebox` is not used, but why? I'll leave the answer to experts (perhaps, there's a bug with `\scalebox`, I don't know)

Comment: If you put your image in `\fbox{...}`, you will see, that on the right side of TikZ picture is more white space than on the left and that the box `fbox` as `\scalebox` are perfectly centered. With adding `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`  this additional white space is eliminated. So, there is no bug in `scalebox`. This phenomena happen at all boxes.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer of course there are no bugs in scalebox, you know who implemented that iI assume?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If you ask this way, I assume it's your doing then;-) Well, no bug then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tikz picture is just like a letter.

If you go

```
\begin{center}
a
\end{center}
```

then the a is centered, but if you go

```
\begin{center}
\fbox{
a}
\end{center}
```

the box is centred but the a is off-center as there is a word space on the left.

```
\begin{center}
\fbox{%
a}
\end{center}
```

is like

```
\begin{center}
\fbox{a}
\end{center}
```

and again the a is centred.

The same positioning of a happens if you use `\mbox` or `\scalebox` but it is easier to see what is happening with `\fbox`.